# SAML integration is breaking after upgrading to spring boot 3.0.6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml

I have integrated SAML with Spring Security, and recently upgraded to spring 3.0.6. After upgrading the SAML integration is broken. Below is the problem description.

After successful authentication, redirecting to "https://example.com/contextPath/login/saml2/sso/app", and this request is getting success in spring 5, and getting fail in Spring 6. After debugging spring internals found below code difference.

In Spring 5 : While executing the redirected request, **requiresAuthentication()** method always returns **false** and executes successfully. Below is the code snippet in Spring 5.

> ```
> package org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.servlet.filter; 
>
> public class Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
>
> @Override
> protected boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
>     return (super.requiresAuthentication(request, response) && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(Saml2ParameterNames.SAML_RESPONSE)));
>   }
>
> }
> ```

In Spring 6 : While executing the redirected request, **requiresAuthentication()** method returns **true** and getting the error response. Below is the code snippet in Spring 6.

```
package org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication;

public class Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

@Override
protected boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return super.requiresAuthentication(request, response);
}

}
```

Please suggest how to proceed with Spring 6.

Below is the SAML configuration.

```
http.saml2Login(saml2 -> {      saml2.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistrations());
saml2.defaultSuccessUrl("https://example.com/contextPath/login/saml2/sso/app");
saml2.authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider));
saml2.successHandler(new SAMLLoginSuccessHandler());
            });
```

I have added cookie to the response like below

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("auth", jwtToken);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setSecure(true);
cookie.setPath("/contextPath");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

When its redirected, its inspected in the browser and below is the image
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHKxa.png)

when the redirected request is sent below is the image.
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f2Eo.png)